# Is there a way of Implementing a Select Condition in LINQ DataContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am working in a MVC3 project, and i am using LINQ to SQL. I have a database schema that uses a field to indicate if the record is active or deleted (field is boolean named "Active").
Now suppose there are two table linked such as State, and City, where City references State.
Let's say i have a method that returns a list of states:

```
public ActionResult ListStates()
{
   return View(_repository.ListStates());
}
```

Now, i have implemented the repository method to return all states, and i could implement it in the following way:

```
public class Repository
{
   public IQueryable<State> ListStates()
   {
      return dataContext.States.Where(p => p.Active == true)
   }
}
```

In the view i could be sure i'm using only active states. But to be sure i'm using only active cities i would need to filter it in view, which makes the view uglier, or implement a custom view model. Both cases are valid, but they require a lot of work.
I have seen there are methods in data context where we can implement certain operations before an object gets inserted/updated into database, as this examle:

```
public partial class DatabaseDataContext
{
   partial void InsertState(State instance)
   {
      instance.Active = true;
      this.ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
   }
}
```

The above method gets executed whenever an insert of the State object is happening.
My question is, is there a way to implement a condition only in one place for an object, for example to return only active records whenever a select is performed?

Comment: remember Ctrl+K is the key :D

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to eliminate the need of specifying **.Where(p => p.Active == true)** on methods of your repositories and you want to define it only once.

I'm not sure whether you can achieve this without creating a data context wrapper, because for each query you have to combine two logical expressions, the expression that comes from repository and **p => p.Active == true**.

The most simplest solution would be as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// A generic class that provides CRUD operations againts a certain database
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="Context">The Database context</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T">The table object</typeparam>
public class DataContextWrapper<Context> where Context : DataContext, new()
{
    Context DataContext;


    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the connection string variable in web.config
    /// </summary>
    string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return "Connection String";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor that instantiates a new DataContext object and associates the connection string
    /// </summary>
    public DataContextWrapper()
    {
        DataContext = new Context();
        DataContext.Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    }


    protected IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>([Optional] Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) where T : class, new()
    {
        //get the entity type
        Type entity = typeof(T);
        //get all properties
        PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetProperties();

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> isRowActive = null;
        //we are interested in entities that have Active property ==> to distinguish active rows
        PropertyInfo property = entity.GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.Name == "Active").SingleOrDefault();

        //if the entity has the property
        if (property != null)
        {
            //Create a ParameterExpression from
            //if the query is specified then we need to use a single ParameterExpression for the whole final expression
            ParameterExpression para = (query == null) ? Expression.Parameter(entity, property.Name) : query.Parameters[0];

            var len = Expression.PropertyOrField(para, property.Name);
            var body = Expression.Equal(len, Expression.Constant(true));
            isRowActive = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, para);
        }

        if (query != null)
        {
            //combine two expressions
            var combined = Expression.AndAlso(isRowActive.Body, query.Body);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(combined, query.Parameters[0]);
            return DataContext.GetTable<T>().Where(lambda);
        }
        else if (isRowActive != null)
        {
            return DataContext.GetTable<T>().Where(isRowActive);
        }
        else
        {
            return DataContext.GetTable<T>();
        }

    }

}
```

And then you can create your repositories like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// States Repository
/// </summary>
public class StatesRepository : DataContextWrapper<DEMODataContext>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all active states
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>All active states</returns>
    public IEnumerable<State> GetStates()
    {
        return base.GetItems<State>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all active states
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pattern">State pattern</param>
    /// <returns>All active states tha contain the given pattern</returns>
    public IEnumerable<State> GetStates(string pattern)
    {
        return base.GetItems<State>(s=>s.Description.Contains(pattern));
    }

}
```

The usage:

```
StatesRepository repo = new StatesRepository();
var activeStates = repo.GetStates();
```

and

```
var filtered = repo.GetStates("Al");
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Although your solution is great, it's still not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the dynamic linq library:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

I've used this before to insert a `Where IsActive = true` into all select statements before.

Comment: No, i'm not looking for dynamic querying, i'm looking for a way to override/implement the default select behaviour for an object in data context.